# Verify a user's affiliation with an organization

Tags: authentication, openid

I'm in charge of IT at a students' organization. Let's call it `FratA`. `FratA` has ties to sister-organizations in other university cities in my country. Let's call those `FratB` through `FratZ`. These inter-organizational ties are formalized by an umbrella organization, of which `FratA`-`FratZ` are members. Let's call it `SuperFrat`.

`SuperFrat` is planning an event for all the student members of `FratA`-`FratZ`, and wants to sell tickets to the event using a web store provided by `TicketSellingCorp`.
However, the sale of tickets should be limited to members of the organizations `FratA`-`FratZ`.

`TicketSellingCorp` has approached me with an unusual inquiry:

```
We want users to type in their username and password to the FratA-website,
 so our web store can log in behind the scenes, scrape their personal/contact information
 from their normally protected profile page and use this information for ticket sales.
Don't worry about security, we won't store passwords, and our backups are encrypted.
```

The main problem is that once logged in, our members can not only access their own information, but also a lot of information about other people.
So if member Alice does not agree with `TicketSellingCorp`'s proposed implementation, her information would still be exposed to `TicketSellingCorp` if Bob *does* agree.

I told `TicketSellingCorp` that I think this is a bad idea that conflicts our members' interests, and I offered them an openID provider (including an OSS sample client implementation) for the `FratA`-website; one that only tells the openID client that authentication was successful or not. It does not even share any information, such as an email address.
My motivation for that is that `TicketSellingCorp` can ask users for that themselves, so users are responsible for sharing their own information.

`TicketSellingCorp`'s response to this was:

```
We cannot implement openID in our sales process.
```

Is there another way to cooperate with `TicketSellingCorp` that does not involve exposing *all* our members' personal information?

Comment: Use another `TicketSellingCorp`. They clearly have no clue about security and no interest in protecting your users.

Comment: Exactly my thought. Sadly, `SuperFrat` is calling the shots regarding which company to work with.

Comment: @derabbink - I don't see a lot of options if the company refuses to work with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about generating a special code for each user that can be entered on `TicketSellingCorp`'s website? You can give `TicketSellingCorp` a list of valid codes. `TicketSellingCorp` can ask users for their name and other personal info when registering, and this could optionally be checked against your own database later.

The codes should be generated randomly to prevent people from guessing other people's code (impersonating them). 128 bits of randomness should be more than enough to make sure they can't be guessed. For example an easy way to get codes is to get 16 bytes of output from a secure pseudo-random number generator (`/dev/urandom` or in PHP `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`), then convert it to hexadecimal and store it somewhere in the database.

If `TicketSellingCorp` is really set on logging in with the user's account, you could make the codes work as secondary passwords that only give out certain information. Also if they're so set on doing that, I'd trust them even less.

Comment: That's a nice angle! I'd go even further and give each user a secondary (random) user name as well. Each secondary username is only valid for *one* successful try, and *five* unsuccessful tries, after which a new one will be generated.

Comment: @derabbink Who said they need a username anyway ;). The codes are random and unique for everyone.

Comment: I was thinking about usability: if the username is shorter than 128b (and based on dictionary entries), users might be able to spot copy-paste errors earlier. That way they'd only need to re-paste the password if the made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

We found another way of doing things: When users are signed into our website, they'll find a link that takes them to the company's "become a customer form".
Part of this link are two request parameters: one (pseudo)randomly generated number, and an encrypted version of that number (a digital signature). The encryption happens asymmetrically (with our private key), and we gave the company our public key.
If they can decrypt the second value, they know that the user came from us.

It's not very elegant, imho, but it works well enough.

The reason we did not opt for [Luc's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42127/16232) is that we suspected that our users would not understand the procedure. Also, after some back and forth with `TicketSellingCorp`, it turned out that they were more flexible than they initially presented themselves.

Comment: I've seen plenty of actions that had a code that a user needed to enter on the website. Tell them it's an "invite code" to the event? Well the case is solved so I guess it doesn't matter anymore now, I just don't see why users wouldn't understand it.